# fetch()を含むライブラリをTypeScriot/nodejsで利用したいが、グローバル変数の置き換えがよく分からない

Tags: aws, node.js, typescript

`aws-amplify` というライブラリをnodejsで利用したいです。  
このライブラリは fetch APIを利用しているため、 JavaScript/nodejsの場合は以下のように `node-fetch` を用いることで解決していました。

```
const amplify = require('aws-amplify');
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

しかし、TypeScriptで同様の設定をする方法がわかりません。
`declare`キーワードなど、グローバル変数（型？）を指定する方法があるらしいことは分かったのですが、 `node-fetch` の実装と差し替えるにはどう記述すれば良いのかわかりませんでした。

どうすればfetchが使えるか、または参考資料などご助言・ご連携いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じで置換可能でした。

```
import fetch, { Request, RequestInit, Response } from 'node-fetch';

interface Global { fetch(url: string | Request, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response> }
declare var global: Global
global.fetch = fetch
```